# Retrieving an image from a cell to share on FB/Twitter using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, ios8-share-extension

I have a customised UITableViewCell where I'm populating an image by first downloading it as **follows**

```
let url = NSURL(string: imageurl1[indexPath.row])

                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        //
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                            if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {

                                cell.postedImage.image = image
                            }

                        })

                    }


                }
                task.resume()
```

Here's the **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feed1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! feed

            cell.delegate = self

            if imageurl1[indexPath.row].isEmpty {

                cell.postedImage.image = UIImage(named: "no_image.jpg")

            }
            else
            {

                let url = NSURL(string: imageurl1[indexPath.row])

                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        cell.postedImage.image = UIImage(named: "no_image.jpg")
                                                }
                    else
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                            if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {

                                cell.postedImage.image = image

                            }

                        })

                    }


                }
                task.resume()



            }
            cell.username.text = username1[indexPath.row]
            **cell.reportPress.tag = indexPath.row**
        }
return cell
}
```

The images get uploaded properly into appropriate cells. I have a share button which when pressed will open an action sheet and it has buttons as share on FB etc. I'm able to add a default text when the Facebook thing pops up. **Now I want to get the image from that particular cell where the share button is pressed**. I know how to detect which share button of which cell is pressed but I'm unable to get the image from that cell as it's not stored anywhere.

**Action sheet for fb**

```
func report() {

    let actionSheetControllerIOS8: UIAlertController = UIAlertController()

        let cancelActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            print("Cancel")
        }
        actionSheetControllerIOS8.addAction(cancelActionButton)

        let shareFBActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share to Facebook", style: .Default)
        { action -> Void in
            print("FB shared")

            //////////////
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
                var fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

                fbShare.addImage(UIImage(named: "whatever.png"))

                fbShare.setInitialText("Hello")
                self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            /////////////
        }
        actionSheetControllerIOS8.addAction(shareFBActionButton)

        self.presentViewController(actionSheetControllerIOS8, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

The report function is called when a button is pressed in feed.swift

Here's **feed.swift**

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegator {
func report()
}

@IBAction func reportBut(sender: AnyObject) {

   self.delegate.report()
   print(reportPress.tag)

}
```

As you can see I can add an image whatever.png and it shows up when the facebook thing pops up. Should I save the image for all the cells somewhere and then access it somehow using indexPath.row? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Are you using UIImageView to show the image? You can get the image from the ImageView with imageView.image. The image must be stored somewhere because it is shown on the screen.

Comment: Yes I am (postedImage is a UIImageView) but I can't access it outside the cellForRowAtIndexPath as it's a customised cell.

Comment: You can fetch the image from Imageview right?

Comment: If there's no cell involved, yes I can. But since the postedImage is a UIImageView in a customised cell file called feed.swift, I can access it using cell.postedImage in cellForRowAtIndexPath but not outside it

Comment: First get the cell using cellForRowAtIndexPath: using the indexPath, then from the cell you can get the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a tag to the share button that correspond to the indexPath.row of the same cell inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   fbShareButton.tag = indexPath.row
}
```

When the button is pressed you will get a refrence to the indexPath.row of the cell containing the image so lets get the image.

```
//sender is you button tht is pressed
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! feed

//you can now access the image like so
cell.postedImage.image
```

let me know if you need more help

Comment: Hey, I added some more code. Check it out! I want to access the postedImage.image outside the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: the code that i posted will let you access postedImage.image  outside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: sender should be the refrence to your button that is pressed

Comment: Even if i ignore sender.tag and just put in 0 in the forRow, it's crashing at that line

Comment: it shouldnt be crashing ! ive tested it just now and its working perfectly ! could you post the error

Comment: Okay it's not crashing now, but I'm unable to get the sender.tag

Comment: you can pass it in the report function, let me know if you need more explanation, cause you already marked the question as answered

Comment: No I got how to do that, just was a little messy.